# VB.Net Fill tables in dataset by data variables

Tags: vb.net

Hi I need to fill a datatable(in data set) row by row by providing the the data by variables in VB.Net. The variables assigns its value by loop.. so the datatable row should be filled row by row until the loop ends. There are three columns in the table. so the table should fill with different kind of datatype variables. pls help.. I need the piece of code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sample code to do it:

**Inserting a New Record into an Untyped Dataset**

```
Dim newEmployeeRow As DataRow = DtEmployee.Tables("Employee").NewRow()

newEmployeeRow ("EmpNo") = value
newEmployeeRow ("EmpName") = value
newEmployeeRow ("Commission") = value

DtEmployee.Tables("Employee").Rows.Add(newEmployeeRow )
```

**Inserting a New Record into a Typed Dataset**

```
Dim newCustomersRow As NorthwindDataSet.CustomersRow
newCustomersRow = NorthwindDataSet1.Customers.NewCustomersRow()

newCustomersRow.CustomerID = "ALFKI"
newCustomersRow.CompanyName = "Alfreds Futterkiste"

NorthwindDataSet1.Customers.Rows.Add(newCustomersRow)
```

Comment: I Already have a dataset DtEmployee and table Employee.. Columns in table are EmpNo, EmpName, Commission... so how can i fill this datatable..

Comment: Check the updated post. See the first solution for untyped dataset.